# Communicate a confirmation code between devices with C#

Tags: c#, hash, tcp, communication, salt

I have a communicating system built in C#. Let's say I have a confirmation code like 123-456-789.

I want to send it thru TCP, but I don't want to get it sniffed.

If I hash it, and send it as a packet, will it work? I know people can still sniff it, but they can't get the raw confirmation code.

Can my system be safer if I salt it, and send the salt in my hash packet too? Or are there any better communicating protocols than TCP?

(Note: Of course, the system is like a login system: People type in the confirmation code, and I will hash the "inputted" code (with the salt) and compare it to the sent hash)

Comment: You can use assymetric encryption to transfer information in a very secure manner.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway people can hack everything if they want. But for bullet-proof and obfuscated system you'd better use this way:

1. Hashing code with salt (anywhere you want, even in the middle of code) 
   Ex. 123**SALT**456**AND**789**HERE**
2. Adding salt for hash (example uses md5)
   Ex. de**21**60f564ad**de**7996e06**ef**af7f**a0**6407597c8b9**34**
3. Sending this string by TCP
4. Recieving on client
5. Decoding hash e.g removing **bold** parts de**21**60f564ad**de**7996e06**ef**af7f**a0**6407597c8b9**34**
6. Hashing every string client want using rule #1 (adding salt)
7. Comparing decoded hash and client's hashed string

When forming hash you can also store timestamp somewhere and form **bold** parts according to it (for example if second is even you can place **bold** parts in other places)

It should be enough for login system if you afraid only MITM attack with sniffing packet (your software part should be protected)

But if you need really bullet-proof system it's better to use symmetric encryption (for white house login system purposes for example)